# Ordenamiento de datos .net

Tags: sql, asp.net, linq, .net-core, net

disculpen tengo un inconveniente con la optimización de un código.
Se recauda una colección de datos de un (SP) y está rápida, sin embargo el código actual hace una agrupación y un conteo por linq (creo que ese es el nombre)

El código es el siguiente:

```
var tem = (from ts in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList()
                           orderby ts.dateArm
                           select new ExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL
                           {
                               total = (from tsbox in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList()
                                        where tsbox.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == ts.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                        select new ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL
                                        {
                                            box = tsbox.box
                                        }).ToList().Count,
                               dateArm = ts.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                               operatorName = (from tsbox in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList()
                                               where tsbox.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == ts.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                               select new ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL
                                               {
                                                   operatorName = tsbox.operatorName
                                               }).GroupBy(g => new { g.operatorName }).Select(i => i.FirstOrDefault()).Select(i => i.operatorName).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b),
                               lineName = (from tsbox in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList()
                                           where tsbox.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") == ts.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                           select new ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL
                                           {
                                               lineName = tsbox.lineName
                                           }).GroupBy(g => new { g.lineName }).Select(i => i.FirstOrDefault()).Select(i => i.lineName).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ", " + b)
                           }).ToList();

                tem = tem.GroupBy(g => new { g.dateArm }).Select(grp => grp.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
                response.infoDataBoxes = tem;
```

> lineName = "AB5", dateArm = "2021-01-20", operatorName = "Nombre 1,Nombre 2", total = 209

> lineName = "AB5", dateArm = "2021-01-21", operatorName = "Nombre 2, Nombre 3", total = 43

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cosa es que me regresa ahí 5 registros

Estoy tratando de  pasar la información a un foreach (según yo por procesamiento)

Mi código es el siguiente!

```
var total = 0;
                List< ExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL> auxExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL = new List<ExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL>();
                foreach (var ts in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"TS {ts}");
                    var objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL = new ExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL();
                    total = 0;
                    string dateArm = "";
                    List<String> operatoName = new List<String>();
                    List<String> lineName = new List<String>();
                    foreach (var tsbox in responseSQL[0].Cast<ExtPackedArmingReporDataSQL>().ToList())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"TS {tsbox}");
                        if (ts.dateArm == tsbox.dateArm)
                        {
                            total++;
                            dateArm = ts.dateArm.ToString("yyyy-mm-dd");
                            operatoName.Add(tsbox.operatorName);
                            lineName.Add(tsbox.lineName);
                        }
                    }
                    objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL.total = total;
                    objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL.dateArm = dateArm;
                    objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL.operatorName = operatoName.ToString();
                    objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL.lineName = lineName.ToString();
                    auxExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL.Add(objExtPackedArmingReporDataCountSQL);
                }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Sin embargo, no me los regresa por fecha agrupados, la sumatoria si sale bien!
Pero la si son de resultado 209..

me regresa el total bien..

pero me regresa 209 registros de esa fecha!

Me podrían ayudar y/o hacer mensión cual sería una buena práctica para optimizar eso.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Saludos!

Comment: No entiendo.. linq hace el for tal cual lo haces vos.. cual es el problema con linq? ojo, en algunos casos, hacerlo todo a mano es mas rapido.. pero habria que revisar absolutamente todo eso...

Comment: EL linq, lo que hace ahí. 
Agrupa y regresa los datos ordenados o agrupados, para una grafica. 
Sin embargo, ese linq, con 401 registros regresados del sp! tarda como 30 seg. 

si se ponen más de 12K tarda al rededor de 20 min. 
Entonces quería ver es posible mejorar el performance con un forEach, (agrupando como lo hace el linq)

Comment: yo dudo que tu cuello de botella sea ahi... pero puede ser... igual, no entiendo cual es tu pregunta...

Comment: La agrupación debe quedar igual que con el linq, porque se tarda mucho. 
Quería ver si hubiese una mejora para optimizar eso!

Comment: capaz que si.. habria que probar y probar.. pero cual es la pregunta para el sitio?

Comment: Que no me queda la agrupación, si me hace el conteo de 289 registros por la fecha!
Peor no me agrupa por fecha, me regresa 289 registros, con el total de 289, en lugar que sea un solo registro con el total de 289, y el otro y no me agrupa, las lineas de operaciones y de operadores, en  si, me regresa todos los 401 registros, en lugar de 5 (ya agrupados por fechas, operadores y lineas)

Comment: ok. perfecto.. no veo ningun diccionario en ningun lado, como para que estes generando una agrupacion...